# Рандом картинок в picturebox без повторений с#(WF)

Tags: c#, winforms

очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. На форме 8 picturebox загружаю в них картинки рандомно :

```
Image[] img = new Image[8];
img[0] = Image.FromFile("pic0.png");
img[1] = Image.FromFile("pic1.png");
// и т.д
 Random rnd = new Random();
 pictureBox1.Image = img[rnd.Next(0, 8)];
 pictureBox2.Image = img[rnd.Next(0, 8)];// и т.д
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как сделать так, чтобы картинки не повторялись ?

Comment: Создаешь список из всех возможных путей до картинок. По мере надобности рандомно берешь один путь, загружаешь картинку и удаляешь путь из списка... В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Для начала не создавайте новый Random каждый раз.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
img = img.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();
```